# How see analytics about branch links created using mobile SDK

Tags: branch.io

I am creating dynamic branch links using Android SDK

https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking#creating-a-deep-link

These are then shared to social media

How do I track things like click events, installs etc as I do not believe they show up in the dashboard quick links view? https://dashboard.branch.io/quick-links

Is there a HTTP API I can use to interrogate all links I may have dynamically created that are part of the same campaign?

Answer (score 4):

Alex from Branch.io here:

You are correct that SDK-generated links do not show up in the Quick Links view on the dashboard. Most SDK-created links are 'disposable' (in that they get used once and then regenerated the next time), so showing every link there individually would quickly overwhelm the UI. It is possible to override this on a link-by-link basis with the `type` parameter, as detailed [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/configuring-links/guide/#other-parameters).

However, you *can* access the numbers in aggregate, segmented by `campaign` value, which I believe is what you want anyway. This is not currently available through the API, but you can see these statistics through the Sources report on the dashboard: https://dashboard.branch.io/sources

Comment: thanks. The Sources report gives us the info we needed

Comment: updated link for documentation https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/deep-linking-api

Comment: It appears that there is a way to do this in the API, but I cannot find anything in the SDK. Is there a parameter for this still in the mobile SDK?

Comment: @MatthewKnippen did you find a way to do this in the mobile SDK?

Comment: @vburojevic No luck unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

you must include a "type": 2 in your branch params

https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/deep-linking-api
[image]

```js
const branchConfig = {
  "branch_key": environment.branchio.key_live,
  "type": 2,
  "data": {
    "$marketing_title": (params.job_name ? params.job_name : ""),
  }
};
```

Comment: This looks great for the API, but I'm wondering if it's exposed to the mobile SDKs

Answer (score 0):

Just updating on Joe's answer
Unfortunately, `type:2` is not supported for deep links via rest api w.e.f
13 January 2022
https://github.com/BranchMetrics/branch-deep-linking-public-api/issues/46

Hope they add it back. I don't know how to see individual detailed stats for a deep link. Adding ?stats=1 doesn't show any stats even though aggregate stats are shown in the sources dashboard
Maybe I'm missing something